# iOS: Choosing specific Closed Captions EIA-608

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, closed-captions

There is lot of mystery around CC608 usage under iOS.

Apple's [UsingHLS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html) offers to declare them in the manifest like this:

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=CLOSED-CAPTIONS,GROUP-ID="cc",NAME="CC1",LANGUAGE="en",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,INSTREAM-ID="CC1"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=CLOSED-CAPTIONS,GROUP-ID="cc",NAME="CC2",LANGUAGE="sp",AUTOSELECT=YES,INSTREAM-ID="CC2"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1000000,SUBTITLES="subs",CLOSED-CAPTIONS="cc" x.m3u8
```

But Apple's [official sample stream](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_16x9/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8) do include CC608 embedded into the MPEG, and still they didn't list them in their manifest!

On that sample stream, I can turn CC608 **on** using **closedCaptionDisplayEnabled=YES**, but this method does not allow selection of a specific language.

In Apple's dev forum I have found [this question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19976) with a promising answer:

> Are you still calling "player?.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled=true"?
>
> There's no need to do that.   If you author your HLS playlist properly
>   with the appropriate language tags, the user can enable captions in
>   the language of their choice, or disable them completely as well.

I was failing to find API in iOS which will allow me to:

1. Read the list of available CC608 streams
2. Activate CC for a specific language

Would appreciate your help with this!

Comment: doest it work now?